# Algebra, finding the elements of the field and solving irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to do this problem from a practice final but there are no solutions.[image]

I honestly am pretty stumped.

My thought was since it has 7 elements, then the degree of the polynomial must be one and we must be working with the field $F_7$

1a) I have no idea what that means, would the squares and cubes just be $0^2, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2 ... , 7^2$ and $0^3, ... ,  7^3$?

1b) My thought is, the field F is 7, so L must be a field with a polynomial of degree 2, but can it just be any polynomial? Don't know how to solve the polynomials $x^2-3$ and $x^2+x-1$

Comment: You're right about (a) but there will be some repetitions. The point is to list without repetitions.

Comment: @lhf so for the squares, $3^2 = 4^2$, right?

Comment: Yes, this and more.

Answer (score 2):

The squares in $\mathbb{F}_7$ are indeed
$$
0^2=0,\quad
1^2=1,\quad
2^2=4,\quad
3^2=2,\quad
4^2=2,\quad
5^2=4,\quad
6^2=1,
$$
so you get $\{0,1,2,4\}$.

The cubes are
$$
0^3=0,\quad
1^3=1,\quad
2^3=1,\quad
3^3=6,\quad
4^3=1,\quad
5^3=6,\quad
6^3=6,
$$
so you get $\{0,1,6\}$.

In order to find a field with $7^2$ elements, you just need to find an irreducible degree two polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$. For instance $x^2-3$.

The field $\mathbb{L}=\mathbb{F}_7(\sqrt{3})$, where we add a root of $x^2-3$ is, up to isomorphism, the *unique* field with $49$ elements. In particular, also $x^2+x-1$ must have roots in it. A root must be of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$:
$$
(a+b\sqrt{3})^2+(a+b\sqrt{3})-1=0
$$
becomes
$$
a^2+3b^2+a-1=0,\qquad 2ab+b=0
$$
so either $b=0$ or $a=-1/2=3$. Since $x^2+x-1=0$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_7$, the condition $b=0$ must be discarded and we get
$$
3b^2=-a^2-a+1=-9-3+1=3
$$
so $b=\pm1$. Thus the roots are $3+\sqrt{3}$ and $3-\sqrt{3}$.

You get a field with $343$ elements by adding the roots of a cubic irreducible polynomial, for instance $x^3-2$ (it has no roots, so it's irreducible because it has degree $3$).

There is no root of $x^2-3$ in this field, because this field has no subfield with $49$ elements: a field with $7^m$ elements has a subfield with $7^n$ elements if and only if $n\mid m$.

Comment: so the field with 49 elements is $F_7[x]/x^2-3$? And sorry so do $x^2-3$ and $x^2+x-1$ have the same solutions in the field?

Comment: @user270494 Yes, $\mathbb{F}_7/(x^2-3)$ is a field with $49$ elements. And, of course, the polynomials $x^2-3$ and $x^2+x-1$ have *different* roots in this field.

Comment: Ah I see, so for part b), we are solving $F_7/(x^2-3)$ and $F_7/(x^2+x-1)$?

Comment: @user270494 No, I find the roots of $x^2+x-1$ in the field $F_7[x]/(x^2-3)$.

Comment: so why don't we have to find the roots of $x^2-3$ in $x^2+x-1$?

Comment: and sorry, how does $(a+b\sqrt3)^2 + (a+b\sqrt3 - 1 = 0$ become $a^2 + 3b^2 + a - 1 = 0$? where did the $2ab\sqrt3$ term go, and also how does $a^2+3b^2+a-1$ become $2ab + b = 0$

Comment: @user270494 Finding the roots of $x^2-3$ in $F_7[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ would be another exercise. For the rest, recall that $a+b\sqrt3=0$ if and only if $a=b=0$.